# Utilizando o Git para conectar 1 repositório remoto para 2 repositórios locais em computadores diferentes

Tags: git, github

Eu quero basicamente utilizar 2 computadores diferentes para trabalhar em um mesmo repositório remoto

No pc de origem (onde o repositório local foi criado - branch main) está vinculado com um repositório remoto, assim sendo:
No 2° computador, eu inicio um repositório local com **git init**, faço git clone > **git remote add origin "link do repositório remoto"** > **git pull** (fui fazer para testar se estava funcionando) e aparece a seguinte mensagem:

```
* [new branch]      main      -> origin/main
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details
        git pull <remote> <branch>
If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

E os arquivos que eu criei para dar git pull no rep remoto para ver se estava funcionando direitinho não foram, logo não funcionou

O que eu fiz de errado?

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que seu remoto não tem um branch chamado `main`.

> There is no tracking information for the current branch.

*Não existe informação associada ao branch atual para ser seguida.*

> Please specify which branch you want to merge with.

*Informe o branch que você quer fazer merge.*

Como você está num branch chamado `main` e só digitou `git pull`, o Git automaticamente tenta encontrar um branch chamado `main` no remoto. Como ele não achou, ele pede que você informe qual branch remoto você quer que seja seguido pelo seu `main` local.

## Soluções possíveis

1. Verifique se a URL do seu remoto está correta com `git remote -v`.
2. Será que o branch no remoto não se chama `master` ao invés de `main`?
3. Se realmente o branch no remoto se chamar `master` mas você quer tratar ele como `main` nesse computador, basta associar o seu `main` local ao `master` remoto com o comando:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master main
```

assim, sempre que fizer `git pull`, ele vai puxar de `origin/master` para `main` e quando fizer `git push`, ele vai enviar de `main` para `origin/master`.